# Scrapy extract from every element of a list

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

I have this code in scrapy which creates a list of rows:

```
list_1 = single.xpath('//table[@class="day-table"]//tbody//tr').extract()
```

each element of the list has this example template

```
<img src="test"></img> <div class"class"></div>
```

how can i extract certain part of every element in the list and assigning to an item? My actual code is this

```
for u in list1:

item = classitem()
item['label1'] = map(unicode.strip, list1.xpath('(//tr/td[@class="day-table-seed"][1]/span/text())').extract())
```

i can't figure out how to make the extraction for 1 element at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, you need to use the `u` variable which would correspond to the next row matching your selector. Say you want the `img` element's `src` attribute to be written to an item field:

```
for u in list1:
    item = classitem()
    item['src'] = u.xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first()
    yield item
```

In Scrapy's terms `list1` is a [`SelectorList`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList) instance, `u` is a [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector).

Also note that it is important to start your "inner" XPath expressions with a dot to make them work in a context of the current row.

Comment: Good and short explanation!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear response. I totally don't have a programming background and it's a pain to learn it U_U

Comment: in my example after running the script it gives this error AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: @GGA please replace `list_1 = single.xpath('//table[@class="day-table"]//tbody//tr').extract()` with `list_1 = single.xpath('//table[@class="day-table"]//tbody//tr')`.